# How to make joined random between two strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I have string array name and string array company

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] name = {"Alex", "John", "David", "Peter"};
        String[] company = {"Adidas", "Nike", "New Balance", "Puma"};
        Random random = new Random();
System.out.println(name[random.nextInt(name.length)] + " " + company[random.nextInt(company.length)]);

     }
}
```

I've got

```
Alex Puma
```

That's OK, but I want print all randomed names and companies, such as

```
Alex Puma
Peter Nike
David New Balance
John Adidas
```

How to do it best way?

Comment: what is team?...

Comment: sorry, syntax error

Comment: Put your printlns in a loop and call them as many times as you want?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException That'll cause duplicates. For e.g. three "Alex"s and no "John"s.

Comment: @arshajii the OP never said that duplicates weren't allowed.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException His sample output suggests they aren't.

Comment: @arshajii you are probably right, but this is the problem with poorly worded specifications. They lead to misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shuffle both arrays:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(name));
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(company));
```

Then print each pair:

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    System.out.println(name[i] + " " + company[i]);
```

Comment: What if there are more names than companies? You'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Point is to show the general approach. OP can sort out the low-level details like that. :-)

Comment: Hi @arshajii. I have another one question, if you don't mind. For example, I have String[] name = {"Alex", "John", "David", "Peter"}; How to group it into pair by pair? Or make one group with one name and the second with three?